# Getting error undefined method Capybara.wait_on_first_by_default

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

Updated to latest [site_prism](https://rubygems.org/gems/site_prism/versions/2.17.1) gem and now I'm getting this Capybara error

```
Failure/Error: Capybara.wait_on_first_by_default = true

NoMethodError:
undefined method `wait_on_first_by_default=' for Capybara:Module
# ./specs/spec_helper.rb:27:in `<module:CapybaraHelper>'
# ./specs/spec_helper.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
# ./specs/lendinghome_spec.rb:1:in `require_relative'
```

bundle install shows version:

```
Using capybara 3.5.1
Using chromedriver-helper 1.2.0
Using site_prism 2.17.1
```

NOTE: I tried just removing this line, but the effect was Capybara was not waiting for the elements and kept not finding the next elements. Basically my previous tests which has been very stable were now failing in lots of areas or retrying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That setting was removed in Capybara 3 - and is now the normal behavior for `first`.  If you were setting it to `true` you can just remove the offending line.

Comment: I removed it, but then the behavior of Capybara changed where it was not waiting for first element (looked like it was set to false). Anything else I might have missed? Thanks.

Comment: @ibaralf As long as you're using Capybara 3+ and you're not passing in 'minimum: 0' to the `first` call there is no way to not have Capybaras `first` wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for the element to exist.  That being said it's completely possible site_prism is overriding `first` and/or passing `minimum: 0`.  Add the code that isn't waiting for the element to the question and  a stack trace.

Comment: @ibaralf SitePrism does disable all of Capybaras normal waiting behavior because it sets `wait` to false in `merge_args` which is called from https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism/blob/v2.17.1/lib/site_prism/element_container.rb#L82 - https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism/blob/v2.17.1/lib/site_prism/element_container.rb#L58 .  You can enable Capybaras normal behavior by setting `SitePrism.use_implicit_waits = true` - or you'll have to use the wait_for_xxx, etc methods provided by SitePrism -

Comment: I tried to go through the site_prism code as well, but didn't see it. Thanks for this, really appreciate the help.